# parallel processing framework in java

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am new to this topic. I had decided to develop a parallel processing framework for cloud data processing applications in java for my project. the framework has to divide the given sequential java code and process that sub codes in different virtual machines in the cloud. the framework has to dynamically allocate and deallocate the resources according to the load. My problem is how to develop the framework.

Is there any libraries available to schedule the java code into different virtual machine in cloud? please inform me if anything is available.

Comment: Interestingly, I have been trying to build one as well. 

I already have one parallel processing framework written using plain simple shell scripting and python(fabric). I am not sure if that would help.

Hadoop or storm is more of distributed processing and aggregation of real time/batch data.

I am specifically looking for Java based parallel processing frameworks as there are some additional dependencies to have it in Java. At least, I am looking for Java modules that would help me build a truly embarrassingly parallel processing architecture.

Answer (score 4):

[Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org) and [Gridgain](http://www.gridgain.com) are excellent solutions. Those cited by `yerlikayaoglu` (Hadoop and hazelcast) are excellent too in their domain but they are all 4 very different and depend on the use case. That's for the map/reduce problem

An other one is the allocation/deallocation of virtual machines. It depends on your cloud provider and some other thing. You can have a look at [jClouds](http://www.jclouds.org/)

Answer (score 2):

There are solutions such as [Hazelcast](http://www.hazelcast.com/), Hadoop etc. You can look this projects.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/), a framework which allows basically the same thing, and supports automatic code deployment over the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do real time processing you can take a look at [storm](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm).
Also [Akka](http://akka.io/) provides nice remote actors API for scala and java.